# showing the grid points on the curve

Tags: plotting

Do you have an idea how to show the points on the graph itself?

For example, if I have the plot below and I need to show the points on the curve, how to do that?

```
kappa = Sqrt[0.3458^2 + 0.4477^2];

 para = ParametricPlot[{kappa*Cos[a], kappa*Sin[a]}, {a, 0, Pi/2}, 
  PlotStyle -> {DotDashed, Thickness[0.007], Darker[Red]}]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Recommendation to a new question poser:  Do you see why your line defining `kappa` is irrelevant?  Just put in the value and avoid the useless diversion of computing kappa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html)

```
kappa = Sqrt[0.3458^2 + 0.4477^2];

para = ParametricPlot[{kappa*Cos[a], kappa*Sin[a]},
  {a, 0, Pi/2},
  PlotStyle -> {DotDashed, Thickness[0.007], Darker[Red]},
  Epilog -> {AbsolutePointSize[5],
    {Point[#], Text[NumberForm[#, {5, 2}], #,
        1.25 {Sign[#[[1]] - 0.4], -1}]} & /@
     Table[{kappa*Cos[a], kappa*Sin[a]},
      {a, 0, Pi/2, Pi/16}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot that is what I wanted(:

Answer (score 2):

This is all in the [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html):

```
ParametricPlot[
 {kappa*Cos[a], kappa*Sin[a]},
 {a, 0, Pi/2},
 PlotStyle -> {DotDashed, Thickness[0.007], Darker[Red]},
 Mesh -> All,
 MeshStyle -> Green
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I meant how to show the numbers (ordered pairs) of these points or some of them on the graph.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean. Show what numbers how? I currently have the points the plot is constructed from styled in green.

Comment: To get all of the points in the plot `Extract[#, Most[Flatten[Position[#, Line]]]] &@para`

Comment: Thanks! b3m2a1 and Rohit Namjoshi